# When to use ResolveService

Tags: servicestack

I have a dashboard service that relies on other services to retrieve data. So in order to reuse existing services I'm calling ResolveService for each service I'm reusing.

My question is if it would be better for me to extract the logic from these services rather than resolving the service? In particular are there performance impacts if I were keep calling ResolveService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be cleaner to extract the logic in shared dependencies, which allows for more finer-grained usage (i.e you call just what you need instead of the entire Service). But if you need to use the entire Service response than calling `ResolveService<Service>` is fine.

The performance impact is no different since it's essentially just resolving an a Service class from the IOC and executing it.